# How to ignore collation in mysql query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have got a field in mysql table with the type SET and collation latin general ci and i am querying like this

```
SELECT * FROM `tblCountry` WHERE FIND_IN_SET("KAN", `tLang`)
```

, It works fine in sqlyog, but in phpmyadmin it gives me error

```
#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'find_in_set'
```

So how to ignore the collation type, is there any work around for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tblCoutnry
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(CAST('KAN' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1) COLLATE latin1_general_ci, tlang)
```